# How to get QML syntax highlighting in gedit?

Tags: application-development, gedit, qml, syntax-highlighting

QML files opened with gedit don't have syntax highlighting. Is there a package providing a gtksourceview lang.spec file for QML? If not, has anyone written a lang.spec than can be installed locally?

Comment: I still haven't found anything for gedit, but it's worth mentioning that there is QML highlighting for Sublime Text 2/3: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/QML

Comment: bug reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1463212 o/ asfsf r wer wer wer wr werwer

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but there are several other editors that do support QML syntax.

The best option in my opinion is to use Qt Creator's (the Ubuntu SDK application) editor component. In addition to QML syntax highlighting, it also as context-sensitive completion.

[image: Qt Creator's editor component]

On the other hand, if all you want is a simple text editor that offers QML syntax highlighting, KDE's Kate is a good solution that I use. While it doesn't integrate perfectly with Unity, it still is a nice editor.

[image: Kate]